# Implementing links in a Semantic UI Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, semantic-ui

I would like to link between the pages music (default), novel and cinema. Using a semantic-ui Menu, which I have already made below. Currently the menu shows up, but no links function.

The url changes, but the functions that I am linking to do not appear. I can only see the music function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, NavLink, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Icon, Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import Music from './components/music.js'
import Novel from './components/novel.js'
import Cinema from './components/cinema.js'

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Music />}>
          <Route path="novel" element={<Novel />} />
          <Route path="cinema" element={<Cinema />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Navigation() {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState("music");
  const setActiveItemOnClick = (name) => {

      setActiveItem(name);
  };

  return (
      <Menu fluid widths={3} icon='labeled'>
          <Menu.Item
              as={NavLink} to="novel"
              name='novel'
              active={activeItem === 'novel'}
              onClick={() => setActiveItemOnClick("novel")}

          >
              <Icon color='blue' name='book' />
              Novels
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item
              as={NavLink} to="cinema"
              name='movie'
              active={activeItem === 'movie'}
              onClick={() => setActiveItemOnClick("movie")}

          >
              <Icon color='orange' name='video camera' />
              Movies
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item
              as={NavLink} to="/"
              name='music'
              active={activeItem === 'music'}
              onClick={() => setActiveItemOnClick("music")}

          >
              <Icon color='purple' name='music' />
              Music
          </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I followed a tutorial to give me this code, the Navigation bar appears and looks nice but clicking does not do anything at the moment. Have I written the NavLink incorrectly? I followed this tutorial on medium: https://medium.com/@alicewon4/semantic-ui-navbar-with-react-router-83fd17d220da

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Music />}/>
          <Route path="novel" element={<Novel />} />
          <Route path="cinema" element={<Cinema />} />

      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Changing the code to this. The menu works to it's quite amazing.